# Fancytree - Set folder attribute when node has children

Tags: jquery, fancytree

We are using Fancytree (https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/) for our online help system.

I've seen in examples that a node can have a folder icon automatically when the **folder** attribute is set, either via HTML object class (*class="folder"*) or via JSON (*"folder": true*).

But I want to have the **folder** attribute set whenever a node has children.

I've tried several approaches already, without success. I've tried setting *node.folder* to true when *node.hasChildren* is true, tried that on createNode event, renderNode event, loadChildren event, and tried to visit all nodes on init event.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO, thank you for your question, it would be nice if you can provide some kind of demo or some code of what you have this way people can point out to the specific solution. And please review this post  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution by myself! I remembered from the examples from the FancyTree documentation (https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/TutorialLoadData) that I could post-process the data being loaded and transform it, using the **postProcess** event, and that is what I did.

So, I iterate through the items of my list searching for the ones that have children elements, to set the **folder** attribute to true. But this function has to be recursive, so I can check children of the children and so on.

Let's get to the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function checkNodesForChildren(nodes) {
      $.each(nodes, function (index, node) {
         if (node.children) {
            node.folder = true;
            checkNodesForChildren(node.children);
         };
      });
   }

   $(function () {
      $("#tree").fancytree({
         source: {
            url: "/Ajuda.json", 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=iso-8859-1"
         },

         postProcess: function (event, data) {
            checkNodesForChildren(data.response);
         }
      });
   });
</script>
```

For my case, problem solved!